# Fetch sql procedure data to jquery view dynamically

Tags: jquery, .net, sql-server, ajax

I am trying to create a reporting platform that would fetch the data into jquery table.
I know that in order to fetch data from each procedure I need to create a web service method to serialize the data in Json and an ajax call in the Jquery to that web service method.

Is there any way that this could be done dynamically such that I do not need to manually code a separate web service method and an ajax call every time a new procedure is added to the report?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for real time updates from the server, look into `socket.io` in `node.js`. Or you can set a function in interval which will check if there are any new updates in the server but that might be resource consuming. So be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sp like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_REPORT]
    @SP_NAME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   IF @SP_NAME = 'SP_1'
   BEGIN
    EXEC [dbo].[SP_1]
   END
   ELSE IF  @SP_NAME = 'SP_2'
   BEGIN
    EXEC [dbo].[SP_2]
   END
END
GO
```

And a method like this:

```
public virtual DataTable GetReport(string spName)
{
    string query;
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
    DataTable dT;
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlConnection connection;

    query = "[dbo].[SP_REPORT]";
    connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
    command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SP_NAME", spName);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    dT = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dT);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
    }

    return
        dT;
}
```

The method will give you all **sps** that you add, but every time that you add a sp you will need to add it on the **sp** and used on the **front-end**.